# Dialog gets destroyed and no way to bring it back

Tags: bug, status-completed, stack-overflow-jobs

Steps to reproduce:

1. Find a job that you can **apply now** to, that is a job that actually allows you to apply for a job on so jobs, for example this guy: https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/102980/php-web-developer-in-jacksonville-fl-remora?offset=1&ajax=1&sort=p
2. When you are at the job click apply now
3. Then esc out of that popup
4. Now click the hyperlink that allows you to **Ask companyX a question**, in this example, "Ask Remora a Question"
5. Cancel out of this dialog box
6. Now click apply now button once again
7. Dialog doesn't come back

Error message:

[image]

Comment: Reproduced on chrome, windows, and firefox.

Comment: That's not good - thanks for the report. Will get a fix out soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A fix is on its way, thanks again!